# ElasticSearch: Create should queries from a dynamic list of criterias with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

Using ElasticSearch 7.6 I want to find all points which are inside a list of areas.
There are several other filter criterias that are added to a list of QueryContainerDescriptors and applied on  the final search.

```
 var queries = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<MySearchableObject>, QueryContainer>>();
```

This example works for one area, where Coordinates is a dictionary

```
foreach (var area in areas)
{
    var pointsList = area.Coordinates.Values.Select(p => new GeoLocation(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)).ToList();

    queries.Add(sqs => sqs
        .GeoPolygon(r => r
            .Field(f => f.Position)
            .ValidationMethod(GeoValidationMethod.Strict)
            .Points(pointsList)));
}
```

and also this:

```
queries.Add(sqs => sqs.Bool(b=>b.Should(bs => GeoPolygonShouldQuery(bs, area))));

private static QueryContainer GeoPolygonShouldQuery(QueryContainerDescriptor<MySearchableObject> bs, FilterArea area)
{
     return bs
    .GeoPolygon(r => r
        .Field(f => f.Position)
        .ValidationMethod(GeoValidationMethod.Strict)
        .Points(area.Coordinates.Values.Select(p => new GeoLocation(p.Latitude, p.Longitude))));
}
```

How would I get around to append a should clause for each area in the list?

Similar to this:

```
queries.Add(sqs => sqs.Bool(b => b.Should(
                bs => bs.GeoPolygon(r => r.Field(f => f.Position)
                    .Points(areas.ElementAt(0).Coordinates.Values.Select(p => new GeoLocation(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)).ToList())),
                bs => bs.GeoPolygon(r => r.Field(f => f.Position)
                    .Points(areas.ElementAt(1).Coordinates.Values.Select(p => new GeoLocation(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)).ToList()))
                )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more trial and error, this seems to solve the issue:

```cs
var areas = FindFilterAreas(query.Areas);
queries.Add(sqs => sqs.Bool(b => b.Should(MyQueries(b, areas))));

private static List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<SearchableSituation>, QueryContainer>> MyQueries(BoolQueryDescriptor<SearchableSituation> qd, IEnumerable<FilterArea> areas)
{
    List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<SearchableSituation>, QueryContainer>> queries = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<SearchableSituation>, QueryContainer>>();

    foreach (var area in areas)
    {
        var pointsList = area.Coordinates.Values.Select(p => new GeoLocation(p.Latitude, p.Longitude)).ToList();

        queries.Add(sqs => sqs
            .GeoPolygon(r => r
                .Field(f => f.Position)
                .ValidationMethod(GeoValidationMethod.Strict)
                .Points(pointsList))
        );
    }

    return queries;
}
```